# How is the security bug bounty program doing?

Tags: discussion, security

Last year, SE announced [setting up a HackerOne Security Bug Bounty Program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297423/setting-up-a-hackerone-security-bug-bounty-program) in private beta mode, which has received tons of positive feedback. Since then, it seems there haven't been any public announcements regarding its progress.

So, one year later, it would be great to know:

- How is the program doing? Has it been successful so far?
- Are there any plans to extend the program / make it public any time soon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have not rolled it out yet, but we are still planning to come back to it. Yes, as [Shadow Wizard said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309648/how-is-the-security-bug-bounty-program-doing#comment1010055_309648), a lack of time & resources, and our corporate attorney had a lot of concerns with moving forward before having more of our infosec program built out.

We are in the process of hiring a Director of Information Security who will be responsible for moving the entire program forward, including launching the security bug bounty program.

Comment: Any update on this 2020?

Comment: Any update on this 2022?