# Did Stack Exchange manage to hire a Director of Information Security?

Tags: discussion, security

According to [How is the security bug bounty program doing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309648/how-is-the-security-bug-bounty-program-doing#309660), Stack Exchange is hiring a Director of Information Security.

> We are in the process of hiring a Director of Information Security who will be responsible for moving the entire program forward, including launching the security bug bounty program.

Has Stack Exchange managed to hire one yet? And is the security bug bounty program ([HackerOne](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297423/setting-up-a-hackerone-security-bug-bounty-program)) going to be up soon?

Comment: Yes, we did. She started on June 4th, but I don't have details about when exactly that program will move forward.

Comment: Haven't seen anything published, not even "valued associate #XXX" style posts. The [security.se] community would love to hear more about her, her plans, and how to get in touch with her...